# Droid X supported preview frame formats

Tags: android

This may be an excessively simple question, but I have to write a camera control app which will function on a Droid X, and my test device has just failed.  Is there a place I kind find a list of of supported PreviewFrame formats for the Droid X, or at least whether the RGB format is supported?